# Accessing DLL's with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, windows-7

I have a new laptop with Windows 7 and I am using Visual Studio 2010 on it, and I am not used to other this OS or IDE so this could be a pretty straightforward issue, I am not sure. When I try to debug a project I get the error

**Unable to load DLL 'QMSdkDll.dll': The specified module could not be found.**

And if I try to add a reference to the dll in my project I get this error:

**A reference to *path_to_dll* could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.**

I see this problem when I try to add a reference to any dll so I am wondering if it is a hard drive permissions issue or anything like that stopping VS2010 from accessing and using the dll's. Any help would be greatly appeciated!!

Comment: Are you sure the DLL your trying to link too is a dot-net assembly?  If it's not then your addition will fail as you've noted, and worse still you'll need to use "P-Invoke" and the unmanaged code extensions to make use of it.

Comment: Make sure that the "manageability" of your project and your referenced DLL match, e.g. that you are not trying to add an unmanaged DLL to a project in managed code and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is, the error I am getting is actually from a sample Visual Studio project that came with an SDK I downloaded, plus I see the error with dll's I have that I know to be dot net assemblies

Comment: @Jim: Make sure that you downloaded this project correctly and the DLL is not corrupt.

Comment: @Alaudo: First thing that crossed my mind when I saw the issue so have redownloaded it, exact same issue again.

Answer (score 1):

Try copying the DLL into the bin/release folder where your EXE is compiled.